# owl carousel doesn't show the items of it

Tags: c#, jquery, owl-carousel

I have used Owl-carousel in a simplest way.

```
<div class="row  margin-zero">
     <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 p-0 mx-auto ">
         <div  id="owl-demo">
            @if (Model.CarrouselImages.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(var item in Model.CarrouselImages)
                {
                    <div class="item"><img src="~/@item.Src" alt="Owl Image"></div>
                }
            }
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

so it loads 6 items for item carousel

this is for csss

```
.margin-zero{
margin:0px !important;
}

#owl-demo .item {
margin: 1px;
```

}

```
#owl-demo .item img {
    display: block;
    height: auto;
}
```

and this is for css

```
 @section Scripts{
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({ 
  items : 6,   
 });

});
</script>
}
```

but I view the website it doesn't show any item of carousel(although they are in source code) but not in view site

where could be the problem

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please post only HTML, CSS and relevant JS plus CDN libraries

Comment: What to `p-0` and `mx-auto` do? If you follow the URLs for the images do they show images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had this in html tag

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

that's prevent owl carousel to work correctlt